# Rails Devise : serial alerts repeating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm working on my login page with the Devise Gem. I encounter this weird thing when i click on the buttons. The messages displays itself at the end of the former one instead of replacing it. Do you know the potential reason of this strange behavior? Thanks a lot!

My session/new.rb

```
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email,
                required: false,
                autofocus: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "email" } %>
    <%= f.input :password,
                required: false,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "current-password" } %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

A picture of the render in the browser
[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXnfW.png)

I tried to find where i can limit this behaviour but unfortunately i didn't found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you login unsuccessfully.

It will render flash

Ex: flash[:alert] = "You need to sign in ...."

After that, in `application.html.erb` display this error

```
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

Make sure `notice and alert` in front of `<%= yield %>` and no repeat `alert or notice`